# Math Expression in Views: Date functions like now()

Tags: views

Is there Date expressions or function? I'd like to calculate a duration between a date field and today ? Is there a now(), today() function?
i'd like this kind of math expression: now() - [field_arrival]

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to display the duration between the given date and today in a view then you don't need any calculation.

Just use **time ago** display option and display your given date with this time ago option.

You will have the result something like this -- 1 year 3 months ago.

You can drop text **ago** if you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function. It returns current unix timestamp.
Difference of these two fields will give you the difference in seconds which you can convert to minutes/hours/days as needed.

```
$now  = time();
// If $field_arrival is not a Unix timestamp you can use strtotime() to convert it to UNIX timestamp first.
$diff = $now - $field_arrival;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Date Module. It has a sub module called Date Views which gives you what you want: http://drupal.org/project/date.

The generated sql isn't pretty though. If you can use `hook_views_query_alter` instead you really should since you have better control over the result sql.

[image: Image of the Date filter]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by setting the output format in my source field to timestamp, via custom date format string: `U` then in the expression field I used:

`time(0) - [field_fieldname]`

Now you can see the offset in seconds from now and the field's timestamp, you can convert that into whatever you need with maths, ie:

Hours:`(time(0) - [field_fieldname]) / ( 60 * 60 )`

Days: `(time(0) - [field_fieldname]) / ( 60 * 60 * 24)`

Etc.

Turns out the ctools module expects maths functions to always take parameters, the correlated php function is `time(void);` so no matter what you put in there it will simply return the current timestamp. Hence the time(0).

Answer (score 0):

my approach

```
$rawtime = \Drupal::database()->query( "SELECT NOW() as currtime " );
$timeObj = $rawtime->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Did you try this? Because I can't see it working inside Views' `Global: Maths Expression` input..

Comment: yes , i have tried in controller not in views